# Get URL parameters with rewrite rules

Tags: query, rewrite-rules, feed

We have some rewrite rules and would like to get the url parameters on that pages/feeds.

That does work on regular feeds, but not on those with a rewrite rule.

On regular feeds like `https://domain.com/page/feed/?somevalue=xyz` I can use `get_query_var('somevalue')` and it results in `xyz`.

On rewritten pages like `https://domain.com/rewrittenpage/example/feed/?somevalue=xyz` it is just empty.

We have first defined the query vars:

```
function add_get_val() { 
    global $wp; 
    $wp->add_query_var('somevalue'); 
}
add_action('init','add_get_val');
```

Then we did this rewrite rule:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^rewrittenpage/([^/]+)/feed/?', 'index.php?custom_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule');
```

And did define this query var:

```
function custom_query_var($query_vars) {
    $query_vars[] = 'custom_name';
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_var');
```

Last we redirected to the feed template with a query:

```
function custom_template_redirect() {
    global $wp_query;
    $custom_name = get_query_var('custom_name');

    if ($custom_name) {
        $wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_custom', 
                    'value' => $custom_name,
                    'compare' => '=',
                ),
            ),
        ));
        load_template( STYLESHEETPATH . '/feed-rss2.php');  
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect');
```

This works totally fine. But as already described: When I want to get my query vars (like `somevalue`) within the template on that rewritten feed, `get_query_var('somevalue')` is always empty.

How can I access any query vars within that rewritten template?

Comment: Does anybody have a hint for me?